# Postfix rewrites sender

Tags: postfix

A friend asked me the following, but since my Postfix-fu has not been exercised for years, I thought I should turn to you:

Mail for the organization (example.com) is handled by mail.example.com which runs postfix. There exists a second machine named eservices.example.com which sends email to a number of people. eservices.example.com is not using a smart host and is managing its own mail both incoming and outgoing. However whenever sender@eservices.example.com sends mail to user@example.com, the sender gets re-written to sender@example.com by mail.example.com. How can this be prevented?

I have the postconf output, but do not have permission to post it, so if you need the value of any variable, ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I can't get the configuration I'm unable to help. The only thing I can do is to refer to the [Address Rewriting Manual](http://www.postfix.org/ADDRESS_REWRITING_README.html). If you don't find the answer there we **need** the configuration. Or you have to ask a specialist who signs a NDA with your "friend".

And when the mail is not rewritten by a rule then you can use any address as sender. Even `president@whitehouse.gov.example`. It's the problem of email that you can use any address as a sender.

Comment: Thank you for the link. Implying though that my "friend" is me was uncalled for. I am a Postmaster and live and die by sendmail. I have not run Postfix since its early alpha versions. Had this been a sendmail configuration problem, I would not have posted such a question here.

Comment: @adamo I started with sendmail in the late 90s and thought "why the hell do I have to compile my configuration?". Then tried to switch to Exim and thought "Why is this so complicated to configure 'just mail'?". And was very thankful after using Postfix for it's easy and secure setup. Now use it for more than ten years.

Comment: I am not a sendmail fanatic. It is just that with sendmail I can do anything that I imagine / need. I've written this http://wp.me/pW0O-8h on picking an MTA.